# Windows Task Scheduler won't let me uncheck "Wake the computer" option for a backup task

Tags: windows-7, sleep, scheduled-tasks

I have a problem with my windows 7 laptop automatically waking after I put it to sleep and then I find it later with the battery drained.  I tracked down the culprit using the "powercfg -lastwake" command to be a Backup task in the "Windows Server" section of the task scheduler.

I have tried unchecking the "Wake the computer to run this task" checkbox for this task, but after I do this and reboot, the box is always rechecked again.  How can I make this setting persist?  I have full admin rights to this laptop, but it is on a domain.

**Edit:**  I looked into the domain policy settings as suggested by Dave below and did not find any policies related to scheduled task settings.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was being enforced by Windows Small Business Server 2011 LaunchPad.  In the launchpad application, there is a "Backup" option with a checkbox to auto-wake the computer.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a group policy coming from the domain that is enabling this setting, sometimes you can use the local group policy editor `gpedit.msc` to disable it and override the domain GPO. I have seem this work with other power settings.

Comment: Where will I find such a task policy if it exists in the gpedit.msc tool?  I am not very familiar with the domain policies.  Thanks!

Comment: you can run `gpresult` at the administrator command prompt to determine the group policy the domain is giving you. then `rsop.msc` to see the settings in the policy.

Comment: Based on the output from gpresult /r and rsop.msc I do not see any policies related to task settings.   I will update my question to indicate this.